# Convert conditional (else/if) operators to logical operators (&& ||) with a JS linter/formatter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint, prettier

I have some older React code using a lot of conditionals, e.g. setting a variable using LET then if/else to apply a value.

For readability, I want to change it to use logical operators where it makes sense to do so.

Is there a linter / formatter that can do this automatically?

Example code included.

Cannot do it so far with ESlint or prettier so far.

```
let method
if (play && play.show_question) method = 'question'
else if (play && play.show_answer) method = 'answer'
```

with a linter, automatically convert to

```
const method = play && play.show_question ? 'question' : play && play.show_answer && 'answer'
```

If a formatter / plugin / linter exists which can auto refactor this, please let me know

Comment: To make this more readable, you should explicitly use `… ? 'answer' : undefined`

Comment: Thx but also, sorry to waste your time, because I wasn't asking for code optimisation.  Whilst looking at it again, clearly my corrected code isn't on point, I just pulled one example out of many in the current code I want to auto adjust with a linter.  In the same way I hit eslint --fix with a good ruleset to clear up some of the junk, wondered if this is possible also -- EDIT - didn't want to sound dismissive, your point is very fair, in certainty, for posterity, at least.

Answer (score 0):

You could check `play` first and then take either the question part or answer part.

```
const method = play && (play.show_question && 'question' || play.show_answer && 'answer');
```

For getting a defined false value, you could add a default value, like `undefined`

```
const
    method = play && (play.show_question && 'question' || play.show_answer && 'answer')
        || undefined;
```

Comment: OP is not asking for refactoring recommendations, but how to do to this particular refactoring automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I am talking about the principle of auto refactoring irrespective of the optimal output. 
 Nina is right in her regard, so thx for that.  Sorry for the rushed example, but the question still stands.  I guess it's not possible at the moment (post was a bit of a longshot), I imagine there are too many exceptions to the rule to code this reliably.  It's just Prettier /eslint can do a lot of stuff, e.g. destructuring, just wondered if this was a current feature in any plugin.  Maybe someone daring will make an eslint plugin one day as for me that type of code is too verbose